# gtrendR: How to list out all the sub categories of Google Trend?

Tags: r, google-trends, gtrendsr

I can see the list of available categories and sub categories for Google Trend here
https://github.com/pat310/google-trends-api/wiki/Google-Trends-Categories

[image]

My expectation is to see all the available 'Food' sub categories.

For example, 'Infant formula' is tagged as 'Food' category by Google Trend.
Therefore 'Infant formula' is a subcategory. But from the API url above, this is not showing.

Is it possible to have an exhaustive list of 'Food' sub categories at more granular level?

Answer (score 0):

the packages comes with a dataset named 'categories', accessible as below

```
data('categories')
```

User can then specify the category by using the category id from 'categories' dataset.